# Inferred property from FB

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have wordpress and since yesterday I have very strange problem when I try to share some posts to FB... There are no images, and when I try to use debugger it says:

Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

I searched but I couldn't find help. There are similar questions but I checked canonical urls, thats fine with me.

When I click "Scraped URL   See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" on FB debug tool at the bottom I can't see normal meta tags, but it displays them as:

instead of:

(there is no space between meta and property is missing)

Any help?

I use Seo by Yoast. All previous posts are still working fine.

Answer (score 0):

We started having same issue after 15/9/2017 18:50 UTC

After many hours of researching the root of the issue at least on our case where the **scraper** was returning meta tags like

```
<metaproperty content="BLA BLA XXXXX">
```

since FB was reading the html like this although in any browser or wget or curl was like

```
<meta property="og:title" content="BLA BLA XXXXX">
```

We found that the root of the problem was that something has changed on the FB **scraper** and failed to read meta tags that where provide with spaces or with new line before the the meta tag was closing like this

```
<meta
property="og:image" content="http://somedomain.com/some/path/to/files/filename.jpg" /><meta
property="og:image:width" content="775"><meta
property="og:image:height" content="435"><meta
property="og:url" content="http://somesite.com/path/to/url">
```

after we fixed it to be a one line like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://somedomain.com/some/path/to/files/filename.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="775">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="435">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://somesite.com/path/to/url">
```

the **scraper** started recognizing the og:XXX meta tags again.

So to conclude it seam that after the 15/9/2017 the **scraper** cant recognise og:xxx meta tags if they are split into new lines before the tag closes.

Although if you don't like your metatags to be in multiple lines and prefer its one line and if metatag is closed in same line like this

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="775"><meta property="og:image:height" content="435">
```

it also works

In our case the root of the problem was a minification function used from here https://github.com/mattheu/MinQueue/blob/master/PHP-Minify-Lib/Minify/HTML.php

So steps to check if this is your case (regardless of you use this minification code)

1. check your code if the meta tags are split into more than one line before the tag closes ">"
2. try to disable any minification code, or if your programming skill help you try to find the peace of code that splits the meta tag to separate lines before it closes

If you want sent a url that you have problems and I could have a look and let you know if its the same case or if you don't want to provide publicly a url sent part of the meta tag code.

Probably the minification splits your meta tag before they close to separate lines.

Hope the above helps anyone that suddenly og meta tags stopped working without changing anything on his part.

@N. Tabas since you are on a WP try to disable any minification code/plugin to see if this fixes your issue.

UPDATE 19/9/2017 13:17 UTC it was filled as a bug on facebbok, which accepted and confirmed it as a bug that will be investigated
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173367659888093/

UPDATE 21/9/2017 22:18 UTC According to the filled bug I did at FB https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/173367659888093/ The issue should have been fixed till now. I did not had the change to check it on our production environment, so I will leave a new update when confirmed that the spacing or breaking to new lines the meta tags before the closing line is fixed.